# How to make absolute imports in python

Tags: python, import, package

Hey so I know this question has kind of been asked before, but the answers do not work for me so here it goes.

How do you do absolute imports in python?

Ex.

```
app/
  app.py
  __init__.py
  util/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
  datastore/
    c.py
    d.py
    __init__.py
```

and then in `app.py` I want to do this

`from app.util.a import SomeObject as sobj`

I tried adding the directory to my PYTHONPATH but it did not work

Ex.

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)`

I need to do this for testing and deploying the application to a server and I dont want to do this:

`from util.a import SomeObject as sobj`

is there a way to do absolute imports in the `setup.py` script or is there a way to do a `sys.path.append`?

Also is there a tool that will generate this for you because this is kind of frustrating, the python community, including myself should develop a tool to set up proper testing and src directories to make everyones life easier.

Comment: Why don't you just use relative imports?

Comment: *Which* directory did you add to `PYTHONPATH`? How did you do that? WHat exactly is the problem here?  Why are you trying to do all this (instead of, say, just installing things into a virtualenv or something)?  Testing tools like `tox` will do this for you.

Comment: using tox and then doing a pip install . --upgrade fixed this problem.